# facing issue in triggering SQS notification from aws S3 to Snow PIPE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I am new to Snowflake, Trying to notify the `snowpipe` when a file is placed in a s3 bucket and thru SQL event Notification the `snowpipe` needs to load the data into the respective table.

Below are the steps I have followed.

Step -1: created a table in Snowflake

`create table Customer_Notification (Id  Varchar(10),Name  Varchar(25) );`

Step -2: Created a File Format

`create or replace file format csv_Notification type = 'csv' compression = 'auto' field_delimiter = ',' record_delimiter = '\n' skip_header = 1 field_optionally_enclosed_by = '\042' null_if = ('\\N');`

Step - 3: Created an external Stage

`create stage Customer_Notification_S3 url = 's3://snow-flake-test/ContinuousDataLoad/CustomerNotification/' CREDENTIALS = (AWS_KEY_ID = '*******' AWS_SECRET_KEY = '**********') file_format = csv_Notification comment = 'feed CustomerNotification files';`

Step - 4: Create Pipe

`create or replace pipe Customer_Notification_pipe auto_ingest = true as copy into customer_Notification from @Customer_Notification_S3 file_format = csv_Notification pattern='.*customernotification.*[.]csv' ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE';`

Step - 5 : Get the ARN Number

show pipes; -- arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:306559659303:sf-snowpipe-AIDAUOYDBFUT7Y5DFHK4K-RdvAOUMAMjYD8diWaS1eWw

Step -6 : Open `aws` S3 bucket in the parent folder, click on properties to create an even notification .
Event name - `customer_notification`

Prefix - optional - snow-flake-test/`ContinuousDataLoad`/`CustomerNotification`/

Suffix - optional - .csv

Event types - All object create events

Destination - Selected SQS queue

Enter SQS queue ARN
SQS queue - arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:306559659303:sf-snowpipe-AIDAUOYDBFUT7Y5DFHK4K-RdvAOUMAMjYD8diWaS1eWw

Finally Saved the Event Notification

I have followed the `abovesteps`, even after this, when a file is placed in the respective snow-flake-test/`ContinuousDataLoad`/`CustomerNotification`/ folder the pipe is not picking the file and not loading it.
checked the pipe status too , it is in running state.
NOTE :  I am in a role `Accountaadmin`

Could anyone please help me to figure out what is missing.

Comment: Try giving -  alter pipe Customer_Notification_pipe refresh

Comment: Is a LIST showing the files if you run: **LIST @Customer_Notification_S3 pattern='.*customernotification.*[.]csv';**

Comment: The prefix contains the bucket name; since the stage is formed to the exact location, the prefix is not necessary. Remove it and try.

Comment: Hello Pankaj, Regarding Try giving - alter pipe Customer_Notification_pipe refresh  , i tried this alter statement, after running the alter statement the the notification has sent and the data is loaded thru pipe . but when i place again a new file in s3 bucket it is not sending the notification automatically, again if i run the alter script to refresh then only the file is picked from s3 and data is loaded, r we really need to run the refresh every time?

Comment: Hello Sergiu,  Regarding Is a LIST showing the files if you run: LIST @Customer_Notification_S3 pattern='.*customernotification.*[.]csv'; -- yes the files placed in S3 is visible thru the list command of Stage and also i am able to query the stage too.

Comment: Hello Abhi Reddy, Regarding The prefix contains the bucket name; since the stage is formed to the exact location, the prefix is not necessary. Remove it and try. -- Could you please let me know in which code the prefix needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is old so you may have a solution already, but thought I'd share my findings. I am facing similar issues and came across this article that may help: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Autoingest-not-working-for-Snowpipe.

I believe the issue is that you have a leading forward slash in the prefix name. Try removing the leading forward slash in the prefix.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer. E.g. "If your problem is ... then the solution is to ... because ...". This will avoid the impression that you are asking a clarificastion question (for which a comment should be used) or recommending a debuggin experiment (which is not considered an answer and probably also should be a comment).